# Easy way to generate url from current one with some params modified in Symfony 6?

Tags: symfony

In my case, I need to make a language switcher inside a symfony 6 project so... :

1. Create a reusable piece of code for several Controllers
2. Get current full url (with all params)
3. Modify one param or add it if does not exists yet
4. return the string to use it

For unexplainable reason, I did not manage to find on the Web a symfony easy way to do this.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#switch-locale-programmatically

Comment: @ArleighHix, I saw this link and I used it but my question is larger (modify one params) even if I use an example based on language.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, maybe there is an easier way in symfony 6.

**My service**

namespace App\Service;

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class CommonService {

    private $router;
    public function __construct( UrlGeneratorInterface $router ) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function getFrenchUrl( Request $request ){
        return $this->getLanguageUrl($request, 'fr' );
    }

    public function getBrazilianUrl( Request $request ){
        return $this->getLanguageUrl($request, 'br' );
    }

    private function getLanguageUrl( Request $request, string $lang ){
        $attributes = $request->attributes->all();
        $parameters = $request->request->all();
        foreach ( $attributes as $key_attribute => $attribute ){
            if( !str_starts_with( $key_attribute, '_') ){
                $parameters[$key_attribute] = $attribute;
            }
        }
        $parameters['lang'] = $lang;
        return $this->router->generate($request->get('_route'), $parameters, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL );
    }
}
```

**Call inside a controller**

```
$url_fr = $this->commonService->getFrenchUrl( $request );
```